# Is the energy flow due to a an alternating current constant or cyclic

Tags: power, energy

I understand that the Poynting vector shows us that energy flows in the region outside, or between, conductors, but the maths gets too deep for me to discover, when the current is alternating, whether the flow is constant, or varies cyclically with the varying electric and magnetic fields. Can anyone please resolve this for me?

Comment: It's a vector quantity which usually (to me) means it will have a cyclic nature just like the AC that creates it. Possibly the clue is in the name. I'm not 100% sure but it might be a giveaway.

Comment: For single phase it is indeed cyclic, however a properly balanced 3-phase system has a uniform energy-vs-time.

Comment: @Andy aka: it's a vector always pointing in the direction of the flow of energy (both the electric and the magnetic field contribute to it). Since the energy flow is constant, I think also the Poynting vector also must be constant (no matter if single of three phases).

Comment: @Andy Aka: If the clue is in the name, this is totally incidental. The Poynting vector is named after English physicist John Henry Poynting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the energy flow due to a an alternating current constant or cyclic

In the time domain, it is certainly not constant, it is cyclic and, if the load is reactive, alternating.

Consider the case of an AC current source driving a resistor.  The power delivered to the resistor is:

$$p_R(t) = i^2(t)R = I^2_{max}\cos^2(\omega t) R = \dfrac{I^2_{max}R}{2}[1 + \cos(2\omega t)]$$

So, for a purely resistive load, the power cycles between

$$0 \leq p(t) \leq I^2_{max}R $$

Now, consider replacing the resistor with with a purely reactive load, e.g., an inductor.  Then:

$$p_L(t) = v_L(t) i(t) = L \dfrac{di(t)}{dt}i(t) = -\omega L \sin(\omega t) cos (\omega t) = -\dfrac{\omega L I^2_{max}}{2}\sin(2 \omega t) $$

Note that the power associated with the inductor *alternates* between positive and negative, i.e., the inductor alternately absorbs and delivers power.

For a purely reactive load, energy "sloshes" back and forth between the source and load.

For a complex load, there is a combination of the above; a non-zero net power delivered to the resistive part and an alternating component associated with the reactive part.

The above can analyzed in the phasor domain too but, I think, it is especially transparent in the time domain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the power in Single-phase AC systems is cyclic.
For some values of the phase difference between current and voltage, it can even become **negative** (i.e. the flow goes in reverse) during a fraction of the whole period.

On the contrary, for three phases systems, with balanced loads, the power is constant. It can be seen of one of the main advantages of three-phase systems.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical energy flows from energy source to load between the conductors via electromagnetic radiation, which has both wave-like and particle-like properties.  Energy only flows in one direction - from energy source to energy sink.  It isn't cyclic in the sense of moving back and forth between, say, a generator and a light bulb.  It only flows from generator to light bulb.  Whether the ***amount*** of energy being transmitted varies depends on the load.

Comment: The reference to AC strongly suggests that the question concerns power flow with respect to time.  As user29689 points out below, depending on the angle of the impedance (ie if it is reactive) power actually can flow from the load back to the source during part of the cycle.  In the purely resistive case, power as function of time would vary from zero to maximum with a time dependence of sin2(t)

Comment: No mention of poynting vector?